# Rpy2 - List of List of Dataframes

Tags: r, python-2.7, rpy2

I'm trying to figure out how to use python to do file parsing from XML files into a data structure to pass into R.

What I need to create in R is a List of Lists of Dataframes:

```
Nodes = data.frame()
Edges = data.frame()

NetworkCompListA = list()
NetworkCompListA[['Nodes']] = Nodes
NetworkCompListA[['Edges']] = Edges

Networks = list()
Networks[['NetA']] = NetworkCompListA
Networks[['NetB']] = NetworkCompListB
```

I know how to create a dataframe from the examples in the Rpy2 documentation.

```
import rpy2.rlike.container as rlc
od = rlc.OrdDict([('value', robjects.IntVector((1,2,3))),
                      ('letter', robjects.StrVector(('x', 'y', 'z')))])
df = robjects.DataFrame(od)
```

How do I insert 'df' into a List and then insert that list into another list in python and then write that out to an rdata file to load into another instance of R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `ListVector` requires an object that implements `iteritems()` (such as a `dict`, or a `OrderedDict`). Note that in R data.frames are just lists with a the (loose) constrain that all elements should be vectors of the same length (or a matrix with the matching number of rows can be accepted), and with row names and column names (list's names being the column names).

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector, DataFrame

# rpy2's OrdDict was added because there was no ordered dict
# in Python's stdlib. It should be gone by rpy2-2.5
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict((('a', 1), ('b', 2)))
df = DataFrame(od)

od_l = OrderedDict((('df', df),))
df_in_list = ListVector(od_l)
df_in_list_in_list = ListVector(OrderedDict((('df_in_list', df_in_list),))
```

Comment: Thanks - that works great.  Just need one more ) on the last line to balance out the parens.  Is there a reason to use (( )) around the OrderedDicts or is that just to indicate parallel use to R's [[?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken (no paren-highlight mode in SO's text areas), there parenthesis are for the following. key, value: `kv = ('df_in_list', df_in_list)`. list of key, value pairs: `lkv = (kv,)`. Final call: `OrderedDict(lkv)`